# gcc difference between -pthread and -pthreads?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, pthreads, portability

I have a pthreads program. I have to compile it with gcc -pthread in Linux (-pthreads is unrecognized option) and gcc -pthreads in Sun (-pthread is unrecognized option). Why the difference, since it's the same compiler? However, -lpthread works on both, but I heard this isn't always sufficient.

Comment: It's not a function of the compiler, it's a function of the implementation of the library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Solaris `-pthreads` and Linux `-pthread` options do equivalent things.  Apparently, `gcc-4.x` series accepts `-pthread` for Solaris as well.

You do want the `-pthread`/`-pthreads` option while compiling because it adds multithreading support in the preprocessor and the linker.